# Como crear un archivo csv con un output con resultados de python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Quiero crear un archivo CSV con el output siguiente:

```
Name: ArrDelay, dtype: float64), ('Error: ', 4997    0.001255
Name: ArrDelay, dtype: float64), ('Error: ', 4998    23.361832
Name: ArrDelay, dtype: float64), ('Error: ', 4999    3.900499
Name: ArrDelay, dtype: float64), ('Error: ', 4999    3.900499
```

usando el siguiente código:

```
error2 = pd.DataFrame(resultados, columns = ['Error:', 'eerror2:                                                             '])
```

Me di cuenta que dejando el espacio después de `eerror2` me permitía que recogiese información de algunos resultados. ¿Cómo se puede crear una columna que registre los resultados de tipo  3.900499 como el de extrema derecha?

---

```
'import pandas as pd 
 from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
 from sklearn import linear_model
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import matplotlib as mlp

 data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/base_datos_2008.csv')

 df = data.dropna(subset = ['ArrDelay'])
 df = df.sample(frac=1).head(5000)

 df = df.reset_index()

 X = df[['AirTime', 'Distance', 'DepDelay']]
 Y = df['ArrDelay']

 loo = LeaveOneOut()

 regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()

 resultados =[]

 for train_index, test_index in loo.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X.loc[train_index,], X.loc[test_index,] 
    y_train, y_test = Y[train_index], Y[test_index] 
    regr.fit(X_train, y_train) 
    predicciones = regr.predict(X_test) 
    eerror2= (y_test - predicciones[0])**2
    errr= "Error: ", eerror2
    
    resultados.append(errr)



 eerror2 = pd.DataFrame(resultados, columns = ['Error:', 'eerror2:']) 

 eerror2["Error3"] = eerror2["eerror2:"].apply(lambda x: x.split('    ')[1])

 eerror2.to_csv('C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/PROYECTOS DE PYTHON/DATA SCIENCE AVANZADO/DATA 
 SCIENTIST PARA PYTHON/error.csv')'
```

Y el error que me surge es este: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: ¿Quieres añadir una tercera columna al dataframe que solo contenga los valores iguales a  3.900499?

Comment: Así es gcoronel99 es lo que busco.

Answer (score 0):

Lo bueno de Pandas es que permite hacer algo tan simple como:

```
f = lambda x: x["eerror2:                                                             "].split('    ')[1]
error2["Error3:"] = error2.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Lo que hace este código es definir la columna `Error3:` como un `split('    ')` (cuatro espacios) de la columna `"eerror2:"`, y agarrar el segundo ítem (index 1, el primero sería el primer número de 4 dígitos que aparece en tu columna). Si quieres poner por separado esos primeros registros también, puedes hacer lo mismo, pero pones `[0]` en lugar de `[1]`.

Anteriormente había mandado la columna directamente, lo cual funciona con mi versión de `pandas`, pero creo que con las anteriores no (<1.0), por lo que con este código debería funcionar universalmente (le envío toda la fila, y en el lambda es que agarro la columna).

Comment: DannyTalent aplique el siguiente comando: error2 = pd.DataFrame(resultados, columns = ['Error:', 'eerror2:']) y luego, error2["Error3:"] = error2["eerror2:"].apply(lambda x: x.split('    ')[0]) y me sale el siguiente error: numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) -> dtype('<U32')

Comment: Creo que la columna eerror2: tenía un espacio al final en tu código, no?

Comment: ahora me sale este error :AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: ¿Puedes poner en tu respuesta el código que has intentado? Las columnas de tu dataframe son un poco extrañas, por lo que ayudaría ver cómo estás ejecutando la sentencia

Comment: Ya lo puse arriba DannyTalent.

Comment: Listo! Prueba ahora? Verifica que la columna `eerror2:    ` sea la adecuada

Comment: Pero donde esta el error en el código?

Comment: Si quieres puedes ver el historial de edición; básicamente, antes le mandaba la columna que querías cambiar para que esa columna la spliteara, pero parece que tienes una versión de pandas que no te permite hacer eso, por lo que lo convertí al modo "a la antigua" de mandarle toda la fila a la función y que en la misma función saque la columna necesaria y la splitee.

Comment: No te entiendo.

Comment: A que error te refieres? A tu columna error2? O a algún error que tienes en tu código? Si te refieres a tu columna, la puedes encontrar en la primera línea (al crear el lambda). Agarra la columna `Error2` y la "parte" en 2, separandola por los espacios y agarra lo que está del lado derecho

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se me ocurre es generar otro dataframe, con los elementos deseados y luego concatenarlo. Como sabrás se pueden generar dataframes a través de diccionarios, entonces se podría generar un dataframe en base a un diccionario que tuviera como valor una lista generada por una expresión generadora, con los valores deseados:

```
df0 = pd.DataFrame({"C": [x for x in df["B"] if x == 3.900499]})
```

La función [`concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) puede concatenar dos dataframes de manera horizontal:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [4997,4998,4999,4999],"B": [0.001255,23.361832,3.900499,3.900499]})
df0 = pd.DataFrame({"C": [x for x in df["B"] if x == 3.900499]})
df1 = pd.concat([df,df0],axis = 1)
```

Da como resultado este dataframe:

```
      A          B         C
0  4997   0.001255  3.900499
1  4998  23.361832  3.900499
2  4999   3.900499       NaN
3  4999   3.900499       NaN
```

En lo personal pienso que esos `NaN` son molestos, pienso que luego ocuparás los valores numéricos del dataframe. Si es el caso los `NaN` serían un obstaculo.

Mi recomendación es usar `fillna()` para que el dataframe quede con todos sus valores numéricos, por igual:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df,df0],axis = 1).fillna(0)
```

Al hacerle `print()` muestra esto:

```
      A          B         C
0  4997   0.001255  3.900499
1  4998  23.361832  3.900499
2  4999   3.900499  0.000000
3  4999   3.900499  0.000000
```

Espero te haya servido.